# I need a SIM modem where I can host 10-15 normal simcards to receiving and sending SMS messages

Tags: sms, modem, gsm, sms-gateway

I'm looking for a modem where I can host 10-15 normal sim cards. The modem will be used to send and receive SMS messages. This modem need to send a lot of messages at the same time.

Comment: consider using services of SMS Aggregator

Comment: why use a GSM Gateway/SIM Rack?

Answer (score 3):

Fifteen of the cheapest available USB-stick 3G modems attached to a tree of hubs is probably cheaper than either building something sophisticated from scratch or looking for the sort of cellular-network analysis kit that might be able to deal with your problem.

Comment: +1 SIM racks are absurdly expensive

Comment: Do you have a SIM rack you can recommend?

Comment: 'Fraid not, we have a bench with 15 x £15 modems :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a [GSM gateway](http://www.hyperms.com/products/60-gsm-gateway.html?_kk=gsm%20gateway).  There are many manufacturers and suppliers this is just one example.  However programtically sending SMS messages through it is likely to be complex and network providers don't like them and tend to cancel sims if they detect that they are being used in gateways.  If you want to send bulk SMS messages you are better off partnering with a telecoms company that offers a web service API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is important that we host the sim cards in a gateway (modem or rack)..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a SMS/MMS Aggregator like www.openmarket.com as carriers will block GSM Gateways if you start to send in bulk.